# Active-sterile mixing for KeVins

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter, neutrinos

People sometimes talk about KeV mass sterile neutrinos as a warm dark matter candidate. I think they call them *KeVins* (horrible name btw). Now, In order for it to be a good dark matter candidate it must be quasi-stable, so the mixing with active neutrinos must be quite small. Can anybody give me the upper bound on the active-sterile mixing? Thanks

Comment: *"I think they call them KeVins (horrible name btw)."* Egads, that *is* bad.